# How to control Mac from iOS

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ios

I have a TV with a Roku box plugged into it, but the Roku doesn't yet have HBO Max as a channel.

When I want to watch HBO Max, I can only do it by watching it in my browser on my Macbook (I use Brave browser).

So to see it on my big TV, I need to unplug the HDMI cable from Roku and plug it into my Macbook (via an adapter). This is annoying but acceptable.

I'd love to then be able to control HBO Max from my couch even though my Macbook is across the room where the TV is.

At a minimum, I want to be able to press Play/Pause on the HBO Max video in the Brave browser.

**What iOS apps will allow my iPhone to control the mouse of the Macbook (on the same wifi network) or at least toggle Play/Pause of the active video in the browser?**

Ideally:

- Is easy to use (e.g. I want my iPhone and Macbook to remember their initial linking setup so that re-activating the connection doesn't require much more than 1 click)
- free
- from reputable developers

Answer (score 1):

If you enable screen sharing on the Mac, you can use a VNC client to connect to it.

Several VNC clients exist for iOS.  You may want to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://remotedesktop.google.com/home) for a couple of years. It's totally free, works across all platforms (macOS, iOS, browser, etc.), and uses your Google account for security. I like it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/products/teamviewer/) seems to meet my goal.

I needed to enable not just "Screen Recording" in Mac [settings](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-control-a-Mac-running-macOS-10-14-or-higher/ta-p/44699) but also "Accessibility".

[image]